# Adding an external directory to Tomcat classpath

Tags: tomcat, classpath

I have a folder in my C: drive as `C:\app_config\java_app`
This folder contains some locale specific property files.

I have a java class (`PrjPropertilesLocator`) that loads the property files based on default locale on the startup of the web App.My web application is running inside tomcat.
The problem is how should i set this directory `C:\app_config\java_app` in the tomcat classpath so that this becomes available to the ResourceBundle inside the `PrjPropertilesLocator` class.
Is there a way i can set this folder specifically for a Single web app that needs it.I do not want to put the property files inside `WEB-INF/classes` folder.

On weblogic this runs fine.I set the directory inside the weblogic classpath in one of its startup scripts and it works fine.
But on Tomcat i tried putting it in `startup.bat` also in `setclasspath.bat`, but was not able to do so successfully.

Comment: Just read on this link http://www.chemaxon.com/jchem/doc/admin/tomcat.html, that tomcat doesnot use system classpath.I copied all the files from C:/app_config/java_app  to <tomcat install>/lib folder and it worked.Looks like tomcat doestnot use system classpath.Can we set the folder C:\app_config\java_app inside one of tomcats startup files.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Just specify it in `shared.loader` or `common.loader` property of `/conf/catalina.properties`.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to specify any of these using command-line parameters. It'd be very handy as I'd not have to modify any Tomcat files for this to work...

Comment: I have spent hours looking for this solution. Once again BalusC has come through.

Comment: People might be interested in [Understanding The Tomcat Classpath - Common Problems And How To Fix Them](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath) as a great relevant article.

Comment: Answer doesn't address key requirement: "Is there a way i can set this folder specifically for a Single web app that needs it."

Comment: This isn't a solution. Two applications may use the same config file name, so applications must have their own unique classpaths to be safe.

Comment: @jacekn: OP asked how to add directory to Tomcat's classpath, not how to add directory to webapp's classpath.

Comment: I used common.loader in /conf/catalina.properties and my properties file is loaded into class path. No issues but I see that the entry that I make gets autodeleted after some time.

Comment: If you are raising your virtual machine with a vagrant, maybe you don't like to edit the catalina.properties file from the provisioner. You can symlink your classes into some of the already-listed directories in the catalina.properties. For example, I did this `ln -sf /vagrant/build/xavi_montero /var/lib/tomcat8/lib/` in my provisioner and it solved the problem.

Comment: Indeed I too want a command line switch to append to the classpath. What good is modifying catalina.properties when I'm trying to deploy via a chef recipe?!

Comment: shared.loader looks like deprecated, at least it was removed from documentation.
But common.loader is visible for Tomcat itself which may be not safe to use.

Comment: typing plus one so that the receiver should know, despite the fact that SO says not to do so :)

Answer (score 31):

See also question: [Can I create a custom classpath on a per application basis in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345793/can-i-create-a-custom-classpath-on-a-per-application-basis-in-tomcat)

Tomcat 7 [Context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) hold [Loader](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/loader.html) element. According to [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) deployment descriptor (what in `<Context>` tag) can be placed in:

- `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` - bad - require server restarts in order to reread config
- `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` - bad - shared across all applications
- `$CATALINA_BASE/work/$APP.war:/META-INF/context.xml` - bad - require repackaging in order to change config
- `$CATALINA_BASE/work/[enginename]/[hostname]/$APP/META-INF/context.xml` - *nice*, but see last option!!
- `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/$APP/META-INF/context.xml` - *nice*, but see last option!!
- `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/$APP.xml` - **best** - completely out of application and automatically scanned for changes!!!

Here my config which demonstrate how to use development version of project files out of `$CATALINA_BASE` hierarchy (note that I place this file into `src/test/resources` dir and intruct  Maven to preprocess `${basedir}` placeholders through `pom.xml` `<filtering>true</filtering>` so after build in new environment I copy it to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/$APP.xml`):

```
<Context docBase="${basedir}/src/main/webapp"
         reloadable="true">
    <!-- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html -->
    <Resources className="org.apache.naming.resources.VirtualDirContext"
               extraResourcePaths="/WEB-INF/classes=${basedir}/target/classes,/WEB-INF/lib=${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
            virtualClasspath="${basedir}/target/classes;${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    <JarScanner scanAllDirectories="true"/>

    <!-- Use development version of JS/CSS files. -->
    <Parameter name="min" value="dev"/>
    <Environment name="app.devel.ldap" value="USER" type="java.lang.String" override="true"/>
    <Environment name="app.devel.permitAll" value="true" type="java.lang.String" override="true"/>
</Context>
```

**UPDATE** [Tomcat 8 change syntax for](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html) `<Resources>` and `<Loader>` elements, corresponding part now look like:

```
<Resources>
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
                   webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" base="${basedir}/target/classes" />
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
                   webAppMount="/WEB-INF/lib" base="${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib" />
</Resources>
```

Comment: Does anyone have an example of this working? We've been playing around with it for a while but haven't been able to properly add things to the classpath for the app to see.

Answer (score 13):

In Tomcat 6, the CLASSPATH in your environment is ignored. In setclasspath.bat you'll see

```
set CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar
```

then in catalina.bat, it's used like so

```
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% 
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" 
-Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" 
-Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
```

I don't see any other vars that are included, so I think you're stuck with editing setclasspath.bat and changing how CLASSPATH is built. For Tomcat 6.0.20, this change was on like 74 of setclasspath.bat

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\app_config\java_app;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar
```

Answer (score 6):

What I suggest you do is add a `META-INF` directory with a `MANIFEST.MF` file in .war file.

Please note that according to servlet spec, it must be a .war file and not .war directory for the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` to be read by container.

Edit the `MANIFEST.MF` Class-Path property to `C:\app_config\java_app`:

See [Using JAR Files: The Basics (Understanding the Manifest)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Enjoy.

Comment: Well, it's not working for me. Note the sources put: You may need to reference classes in other JAR files from within a JAR file. The way may works for `jar`, but not for my web application.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new file, setenv.sh (or setenv.bat) inside tomcats bin directory and add following line there

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/XX/xx/PATH_TO_DIR
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late for the party but I follow below steps to make it fully configurable using IntelliJ's way of in-IDE app test. I believe the best way to go with is to Combine below with @BelusC's answer.

```
1. run the application using IDE's tomcat run config. 
2. ps -ef | grep -i tomcat //this will give you a good idea about what the ide doing actually.
3. Copy the -Dcatalina.base parameter value from the command. this is your application specific catalina base. In this folder you can play with catalina.properties, application root path etc.. basically everything you have been doing is doable here too.
```