# How can I set hibernate database config from outside config file?

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, orm

I need to have hibernate database config set from outside text file, how can I do it? Is there some kind of method for this, or do I have to make my own?

Comment: what is "outside" in this case? Is hibernate.cfg.xml outside?

Comment: outside classpath, so that I don't have to build database config to war

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can programaticaly configure hibernate within your app: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate configuration file (*.cfg.xml) have to be in the class path of your application's war.
But, you can maintain file like 'install.properties'  in deployment folder of your application.

Inside it you can maintain database related properties.For eg.

```
database.name =
database.hostname=
database.username=
databse.password=
```

Use some predefined constant string inside 'hibernate.cfg.xml'  that you can replace during time of application deployment task. For eg.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://$database.hostname/$database.name</property>
```

you can write an  'ant' task which 'unwar' the war then replace constant strings with values as mentioned inside 'install.properties' and then make 'war' again.

In this way you can separate out  configuration settings from application code structure.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate configuration files have to be on the class path but can be outside your war. The exact way to add a directory or files to the class path will depend on your app server so you'll have to mention which one you're using (for Tomcat, see this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300780/adding-a-directory-to-tomcat-classpath) for example).