# How can i add files outside my war to tomcat webapp-classpath?

Tags: tomcat, configuration

I would like to run my webapp on different servers in different configurations. 
So it's not possible for me to place my configs (for instance spring application-context.xml) into my webapp. 
I would like to place it the context folder of the app under %CATALINA_HOME/conf/myapp/localhost. But it seems that tomcat is not adding files from this location to the webapp classpath.

Is this configurable? And if how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add directories to the Tomcat classpath by adding them to `shared.loader` or `common.loader` property of `catalina.properties`

See also:
 [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1863646/80144) (Adding a directory to tomcat classpath)

or

[Can I create a custom classpath on a per application basis in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345793/can-i-create-a-custom-classpath-on-a-per-application-basis-in-tomcat)