# Can I have an application specific classpath directory in tomcat 7, configured outside the war?

Tags: java, tomcat

I would like to have an additional classpath directory in tomcat 7, like what can be done by adding `${catalina.home}/mydir` in catalina.properties, but specific to an application (war).

I would also like this setting to be outside the war (I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345793/can-i-create-a-custom-classpath-on-a-per-application-basis-in-tomcat), but the configuration is within the war).

I my case, it is to have two environments (say integration and QA) on the same container, with different configurations. I wish to keep the artifacts environment agnostic, so not changing the path to the configuration files (properties, logback, ...).

Can this be done ? How ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**VirtualWebappLoader** https://stackoverflow.com/a/6410589/173149:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/websandbox">
    <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
          virtualClasspath="/usr/.../*.jar;/usr/.../*.jar"/>
</Context>
```

This config can be placed in `$CATALINF_ROOT/config/Catalina/localhost/$PREFIX.xml` where `$PREFIX`is context of your application. Use `ROOT` to place at `/`

Comment: Didn't test but it seems to match.