# How do I add a directory to the classpath of a specific Tomcat 7 context?

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, classpath

How do I add a directory to the [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) of the [classloader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader) assigned to a specific [Tomcat 7](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html) context?

I want my Java Servlet application to load a properties file external to the warfile from a directory in the classpath **visible only to that servlet**.  For example, servlet context `/appA` on host `localhost` should load `/etc/appA/application.properties` (Linux) or `D:\configuration\appA\application.properties` (Windows) while servlet context `/appB` on the same host should not have `/etc/appA` (Linux) or `D:\configuration\appA\` in its classpath.

Comment: I think [Can I create a custom classpath on a per application basis in Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345793/can-i-create-a-custom-classpath-on-a-per-application-basis-in-tomcat) is a better choice as a duplicate than [Adding a directory to tomcat classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300780/adding-a-directory-to-tomcat-classpath).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you want to add the path for all webbapps:**

Add directory path name `/etc/appA` to common.loader property of `/conf/catalina.properties` file.

**If you want to add the path to one specific webapp:**

In file `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/appA.xml`, inside element `<Context>`, use element `<Loader>` with class `VirtualWebappLoader` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/appA">
    <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
              virtualClasspath="/etc/appA"/>
</Context>
```

**References:**

[VirtualClassLoader](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/loader/VirtualWebappLoader.html)

Comment: Won't this path appear on the classpath of all contexts?  I want the path to be visible to a particular context and that context only.

Comment: Your answer is correct, except the `<Context>` definition should appear in a file outside the application warfile in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/appA.xml` so that the path name prefix format may differ for different operating systems while using the same warfile.

Comment: Modified the answer to specify file `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/appA.xml`.