# Place Hibernate configuration in a different location

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, configuration, hibernate-mapping

The ideal place for [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) configuration files (.hbm.xml) is

```
.../tomcat/webapps/projectName/WEB-INF/classes/hbm
```

But I want to place those configurations settings in a different location, say

```
/usr/local/properties/hibernate
```

How can I do that?

If I place that configuration files in that location and if I start [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) then it gives me an error on loading that configurations saying

> hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Comment: This should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300780/adding-a-directory-to-tomcat-classpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To configure location of `.cfg.xml` file use `Configuration.configure(File)` instead of `Configuration.configure()` when creating `SessionFactory`.

To configure location of `.hbm.xml` files use `Configuration.addDirectory()`.

**See also:**

- [`Configuration` javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html)