# How to change the Java webapp 'WEB-INF path' convention under tomcat or jetty

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jetty

under a Java Webapp,

I want to set **/WEB-INF/lib**  to  D:/somepath/lib

and           **/WEB-INF/classes** to E:/somepath/classes

and           **web.xml** to F:/somepath/config.xml

how to config these under tomcat or jetty to change the convention?

Comment: I assume you can't do this, since they are all Java EE specifications. But need expert opinion of this.

Comment: You can add directories to the tomcat classpath (affects all of tomcat however, not just one webapp).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300780/adding-a-directory-to-tomcat-classpath

Comment: If your OS supports links, and if you are running an exploded war, you could make these directories symbolic links.

Comment: @keith yes, now I am using eclipse which can create 'linked-file' under all kinds of the OS,

Comment: It's not a 'convention'. It's a *specification.* Why do you think you need something different!

Comment: For this question to make any sesnse, you ought to explain *why* you want to do this. I suspect yiur real problem is actually something different.

Answer (score 2):

The specification (Java™ Servlet Specification Version 2.3) only mentions standard folders:

> The web application classloader must load classes from the **WEB-INF/classes**
> directory first, and then from library JARs in the **WEB-INF/lib** directory.

With Tomcat or Jetty you cannot do it with "out-of-box" provided functionality:

[Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html):

> WebappX — A class loader is created for each web application that is deployed in a single Tomcat instance. All unpacked classes and resources in the **/WEB-INF/classes** directory of your web application, plus classes and resources in JAR files under the **/WEB-INF/lib** directory of your web application, are made visible to this web application, but not to other ones.

[Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Classloading):

> The normal configuration is for each web context (web application or war file) is given it's own classloader, which has the system classloader as it's parent. Such a classloader hierarchy is normal in Java, however the servlet specification complicates the hierarchy by requiring that:
>
> Classes contained within **WEB-INF/lib** or **WEB-INF/classes** have priority over classes on the parent class loader. This is the opposite of the normal behaviour of a java 2 class loader.

However, you can:

1. [Add extra classpaths to Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Classloading#Classloading-AddingextraclasspathstoJetty)
2. [Add directory to Tomcat classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1863646/655249)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix system you could do this manually by setting up soft links from the expected places to the locations on the other disks.

Both application servers you mention are open source, so you could write your own version of them. I guess the part that implements the classloader for a web app is what you would have to change.

But if you must engage in such shenanigans,  you should suspect that you have made a wrong decision earlier.  I can think of no good reason to do what you want to do.