# Deploy project without /WEB-INF/lib by placing libs in Tomcat's common.loader

Tags: spring, tomcat7

I would like to deploy my project without `/WEB-INF/lib`.

I created a folder `/usr/share/tomcat7/mylib` and move all the files from `/WEB-INF/lib`. I ordered this directory for `common.loader`, but the application has stopped running.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl not spring libraries. Check for hibernate-validator jar

Comment: /usr/share/tomcat7/mylib/hibernate-validator-4.3.1.Final.jar

Comment: Have you set the tomcat classpath to your custom directory. 

Refer below link on how to set classpath
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300780/adding-a-directory-to-tomcat-classpath

Comment: common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/common/classes,${catalina.home}/common/*.jar,/usr/share/tomcat7/mylib/*.jar

Comment: Do you have SLF4J jar also(dependent jar for hibernate-validator) in the classpath. How are you building your application?

Comment: hey!!!! A added /usr/share/tomcat7/mylib/ and it works!!! But, why /usr/share/tomcat7/mylib/*.jar do not work?

Comment: Classpath accept specific files or folders. It does not accept wildcard characters